# C# StreamReader Load Data and post to Form

Tags: c#, streamreader, streamwriter

I've been struggling to figure out exactly the best way to handle my situation for a few days now. I'm not able to get the program to function the way I desire. What I have is a .txt file, that has two columns, and 11 seperate lines. It looks as follows:

```
[Data1] 1
[Data2] 2
[Data3] 3
[Data4] 4
[Data5] 5
[Data6] 6
[Data7] 7
[Data8] 8
[Data9] 9
[Data10] 10
[Data11] 11`
```

I've been able to manually extract the lines of data using:

```
        using (var reader = new StreamReader("config.txt"))
        {
            string data1 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data2 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data3 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data4 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data5 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data6 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data7 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data8 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data9 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data10 = reader.ReadLine();
            string data11 = reader.ReadLine();


            // Post results into Form
            labelVersRead.Text = "Data1 is: " + data1 + " Data5 is: " + data5;
        }
```

Which works well enough I believe for such a small file. But I can't seem to figure out how to trim [DATA1] from appearing into the form. I would like it to just show:

`Data1 is: Data1 Data5 is: Data5` << Without have [DATA1] appear in the form.

~I haven't been able to figure this part out. Once I can get this working, I'd like to try to manipulate the Data without affecting the [DATA] portion of the .txt.

Comment: Your question is still a bit unclear to me. Do you want to remove the brackets `[` and `]`? Are you trying to just print out the number values on the line...like `Data1 is: 1 Data5 is: 5`?

Comment: I'm trying to remove [DATA1] and only output "1" on the form. I want [DATA1] and "1" to remain in the .txt, but not to have [DATA1] appear on the form. Yes, I am just trying to print out the number values.  

Also: The [DATA] in brackets will always stay the same, but the values on the right will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar way to do it, without the `Trim()`:

```
labelVersRead.Text = "Data1 is: " + data1.Split(' ')[1] + " Data5 is: " + data5.Split(' ')[1];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! So from what I understand using `.Split(' ')[1]` is simply saying that everything before and upto the (space) is removed? The [1] represents the char or such of how far to trim. I don't really understand the proper language yet; but hopefully that makes sense. I am going to attempt to link this to user input on the form.

Comment: @NooBeX This is how it works: if your sting is `string data1 = "[Data1] 1"`, `Split(' ')` breaks that string down into an array of strings based on the delimiter that you pass it (in this case it is the `space` character). So now you have a string array that looks like this `{"[Data1]", "1"}`. The `[1]` gets the string at index position 1 (the second string in the array) in the new string array that we have. In your case, this string will always be the value that you want. Hope that helped.

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot. I've been messing around with my code a bunch and I've managed to convert the data on the right into an int, so it can be displayed on the Form as a slider. One of the [DATA] goes from 0 to 100. I'm in the process of trying to update the slider and make the changes to the .txt when I hit save. I've been able to show the value of 50 on the form automatically when it opens. However, still trying to figure out how to update the label to show the value depending where the slider is.